Inserting text from a file into a HTML block in powershell
I have asked a similar question before but as my script advances I have more an more criteria that I need to add in.
I have a script now that goes off and creates a random password and stores it in a text file "password.txt".
The script then moves on, uploads the new random password to my router and changes the guest wifi password via API call.
I then have another process which sends an email to various addresses. I would like this email to send the password stored in "password.txt" but so far I can only get it to send the variable I am using and not the text from within the variable location.
# build email message body and send it
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("X-Smtp2go-Api-Key", "api-3A583xxxxxxxxxxx")
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.smtp2go.com/v3/email/send' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"sender":"merakiapi@mydomain.co.uk","to":["me@mydomain.co.uk"],"subject":"Password for Guest WiFi","html_body":"The new password is $pass"}'

Email preview
My variable for $pass is stored further up in the main script $pass = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\password.txt. I am wondering if its location is what is causing the issue but I am not quite sure where to put it.
The varibale is also being used to send the new password to the router.
Update
Thank you @sirtao. I think I am doing something not quite right as I get an error message and it stops my email from sending at all.
# build email message body and send it
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("X-Smtp2go-Api-Key", "api-3A58xxxxxx")
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.smtp2go.com/v3/email/send' -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -Body '{"sender":"merakiapi@mydomain.co.uk","to":["me@mydomain.co.uk"],"subject":"Password for Guest WiFi","html_body":"The new password is "$pass""}'

I get this error:
Invoke-WebRequest : {"request_id": "922f2582-b95a-11ef-a51f-f23c9216bfec", "data": {"error": "Failed to parse json payload: error Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 169 (char 168)", "error_code": 
"E_ApiResponseCodes.INVALID_IN_PAYLOAD"}}
At C:\Scripts\Change_Guest_PSK1.ps1:101 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.smtp2go.com/v3/email/ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

I have also repalaced all of the " after -Body with ' except for "$pass" and I still get an error.
I have to admit, I don't get whats going on with the other way you suggested. I did try it, I hashed out my part and inserted yours but it failed epically.

EDIT 2
the to field MUST be a collection, even if it's a single-item collection.
I was writing it as a JSON collection by error.
I have now fiexd the code and made a free smtp2go account to actually test it.
Using my credentials, it works on both powershell 5.1 and 7.4
EDIT!!!
...I made a lil' bit typing error in the Invoke-WebRequest command.
(used @$InvokeSplat instead of @InvokeSplat)
I fixed it but if uncatched that could have cause errors.
The problem is with the Body value.
You are using ' for it, which makes it a LITERAL string. Thus $pass gets saved as liteal word and not a reference to the variable.
tl;dr:
$Pass= 'MUH PASSWORD'

'$Pass' # prints $Pass
"$Pass" # prints MUH PASSWORD

Also, you can Splat more. Try this:
$HeadersHash = @{
    'accept'            = 'application/json'
    'Content-Type'      = 'application/json'
    'X-Smtp2go-Api-Key' = $apiKey
}

$ToAddressArray = @(
    'me@mydomain.co.uk'
)

$Body = @{
    'sender'    = 'merakiapi@mydomain.co.uk'
    'to'        = $ToAddressArray
    'subject'   = 'Password for Guest WiFi'
    'html_body' = "The new password is $pass" 
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress



$InvokeSplat = @{
    Uri         = 'https://api.smtp2go.com/v3/email/send'
    Method      = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod]::Post
    Headers     = $HeadersHash
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Body        = $Body
}


$Request = Invoke-WebRequest @InvokeSplat


Hi @sirtao I have posted an update in the body of my question as I can never get formatting to show properly in these comments.

I made a couple stupid errors in my original answer, I have edited to have it work correctly
